# My app display black screen when I rotate from Landscapeleft to LandscapeRight and LandscapeRight to LandscapeLeft

Tags: ios, iphone, cocos2d-iphone, cocos2d-x, uiinterfaceorientation

Hi I am new to iOS developer.

I have a problem with my app when I rotate LandscapeLeft to LandscapeRight my app display shows black screen.

I am using this method for rotate.

```
 -(void)willRotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration{

    CGRect screenRect = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds];
    CGRect rect = CGRectZero;


    if(toInterfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait || toInterfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown)      
        rect = screenRect;

    else if(toInterfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft || toInterfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight)
        rect.size = CGSizeMake( screenRect.size.height, screenRect.size.width );

    CCDirector *director = [CCDirector sharedDirector];
    EAGLView *glView = [director openGLView];
    float contentScaleFactor = [director contentScaleFactor];

    if( contentScaleFactor != 1 ) {
        rect.size.width *= contentScaleFactor;
        rect.size.height *= contentScaleFactor;
    }
    glView.frame = rect;
}
```

Comment: Why are you doing this ? what your this method perform?

Comment: when I rotate this method call @Lion

Comment: what you want when your device is rotate or orientation get changed?

Comment: What but? what you want when your device rotate? this method is used to perform some task when device is rotate. so what you want to perform when device is rotate?

Comment: @lion yes I want to rotate the device.

Comment: Do you just want to change orientation when rotate device?